# Re-sizing images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize, adobe-lightroom

I am taking raw images importing at 72 dpi with image sizes often at 5184 x 3165.
The new website hosting company I am working with is requesting the images be at 1400 x 600 px. I am having difficulty resizing the photos without distortion. Is this an odd size?

I'm using Photoshop CC but could also use Lightroom.

Comment: When you change the image size, are you leaving height and width linked or are you just typing in exactly 1400x600 for each picture?

Comment: Are they requesting the images be *exactly* that size, or a *maximum* of that size?

Comment: I am considering the aspect ratio and choosing the best starting point--i.e. if I can crop vertically I choose the width then try to crop down to the height.

Answer (score 8):

It's not an odd size to ask for, it's just not the same ratio as the photos you have.

Basically, if you need to get *exactly* 1400x600 px photos, you're going to have to crop them to be that size.

I would do this in Photoshop.

### 1. Go to Image>Image Size

[image: image size adjustment]

### 2. Leave the height and width linked to avoid distortion and set the larger dimension first

(1400 px in this case)

[image: Original size]

[image: resizing just width]

### 3. Click okay, then select the Crop tool `C`

Photoshop has this nifty feature where it will tell you the new px size for your crop area, use that to get to 600 px.

[image: Cropping]

[image: Cropped!]

**Note:** if you unlink the height and width and set the values for both dimensions, your images will *always* be distorted unless you happen to have taken photos that are the same ratio (Unlikely in this case because I can't think of any cameras that shoot in 7:3).

### What happens when you unlink height and width

[image: Unlinked resizing. this is bad]

[image: resulting squatty image]

Comment: Thanks Ashlee, this is the methodology I was using originally, but I didn't like how I was being forced to crop a few of the photos.