# Photoshop: How to resize image without cropping or distorting?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize

i have an image 1920x900. My client want this size 1920x400 without using crop. i tried to edit image size in image menu in photoshop, but it is not allowing me to do it to maintain its height and width in proportion, becauz 400 is very less than 1920. So kindly help is there any other way.

Comment: There really is only 2 options. You can either crop the photo or severely distort the image to fit the 400px height.

Comment: Your client does not undersatand that it has to be cropped. If you have a layered PSD file you should be able to move and re-size the elements of the document to fit the new proportions. If you do not have a layered document it will be difficult to impossible to resize all the elements so they fit within the new proportion.

Comment: See [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81626/re-sizing-images/81628#81628).